# Form labels not growing to fill flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make 2 labels that I have, fill up a `<div>` that has a `width` of `100%`.

These `labels` are tied to radio buttons that I'm hiding while styling the labels. I'd like each label to fill **100%** of the `height` and **50%** of the `width` of the div they are in but can't seem to get it to work.

I'm also not married to flexbox if there is another way to accomplish this. Apologies but my CSS is not strong.

In the example below I'd see half the box red, half blue when the radio buttons are selected, and no green.

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -1000em;
}

input[type=radio]+label:before {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: red;
  flex: auto;
}

input[type=radio]:checked+label:before {
  background-color: blue;
}

.radio_container {
  height: 6rem;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio_container">
  <input type="radio" name="citizenship" placeholder="Citizenship" value="yes" id="citizenship1">
  <label for="citizenship1" value="yes">yes</label>
  <input type="radio" name="citizenship" placeholder="Citizenship" value="no" id="citizenship2">
  <label for="citizenship2" value="no">no</label>
</div>
```

Comment: `label {width:50%;height:100%}`

Comment: @TemaniAfif tried that https://codepen.io/timbroder/pen/OvRPKr

Comment: keep the container flex ... you should add the code to the one you add in the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work for you:

Just add:

```
label{
  flex:1;
}
```

*Rest of the CSS is just fine, I have also added CSS to align your content if you don't want that just remove.*

A working sample below for you:

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -1000em;
}

input[type=radio]+label:before {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: red;
  flex: auto;
}

input[type=radio]:checked+label:before {
  background-color: blue;
}

.radio_container {
  height: 6rem;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  text-align: center;/* To align the content horizontally center*/
  align-items:center;/* To align the content vertically center*/
}
label{
  flex:1;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio_container">
  <input type="radio" name="citizenship" placeholder="Citizenship" value="yes" id="citizenship1">
  <label for="citizenship1" value="yes">yes</label>
  <input type="radio" name="citizenship" placeholder="Citizenship" value="no" id="citizenship2">
  <label for="citizenship2" value="no">no</label>
</div>
```

if you want to know more about `flexbox` then visit this [link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), Hope this was helpful for you.